# R version update on Ubuntu

Tags: r, rstudio, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed R 3.3.3 and now trying to update it to the version 3.4.1. 
Used the following instructions:

sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base

And after all, the version installed still is R 3.3.3.

Also tried to delete the file from usr/local/bin/R and install the 3.4.1 version, but didn't work.
Thanks,

Roger.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the common linux upgrade command? Works for me on 14.04.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It worked. Thank you very much.